# Can't deploy python code to heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, bots, chatbot

so I just started to learn make a python bot and deploy it to heroku. I want to make a line bot.

I follow the instructions in Line and for tutorial, I download the sample-echo python file and want to try deploy it to heroku.

I follow the instructions in heroku step by step, and when i want to do

> $ git push heroku master

i got error

> -----> Failed to detect app matching https//codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
>   buildpack
>   Push failed

i already set the buildpacks to python and this is the ss of the master directory
[this is the master directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8VVm.png)

I really hope that someone could help me solve this error, and anyway, can anyone suggest a good web to learn make line chatbot using python?

Thank you so much

Comment: I think you did but just to be sure did you try what they said on [this link](https://kb.heroku.com/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack)?

Comment: Thank you so much @EricGodard i solve this problem. I didn't know that i need to do git add requirements.txt rather than put it in the .git thank you so much

Comment: Don't worry, simple mistake like that happen to everyone. I'll post this as an answer, please upvote/accept it if it fixed your problem.

Comment: done @EricGodard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was adressed [here](https://kb.heroku.com/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack)

> Resolution
>
> This error message means that Heroku was unable to automatically
> detect the type of app you're trying to deploy: Ruby, Node, Python,
> PHP, Java, etc. We look for signatures for each language we support
> (like a pom.xml file or package.json file).
>
> Most apps have at least one of these signatures present, so if you see
> this error, it usually means an important file isn't checked into your
> git repository:
>
> ```
> Java: pom.xml
> Ruby: Gemfile
> Node.js: package.json
> Python: requirements.txt / setup.py / Pipfile
> PHP: composer.json / index.php
> ```
>
> You should git add {file}, git commit -am 'added {file}' and then git
> push heroku master.

Adding the file requirement.txt in the .git folder isn't enough, you have to do the command to add it then push it. It should fix the problem.